# Как удалить папку из репозитория

Tags: github, git-репозиторий

Прошу помочь мне с таким вопросом. Через командную строку создал папку в своем репозитории, теперь не знаю как удалить ее. Помогите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Удаляет каталог:

```
git rm -r course_test
```

Для удаления файла используется

```
git rm file_name
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Отметьте пожалуйста ответ, как решение.
Удачи Вам!